# Sacriledge of Altar

Tags: canon, canon-law, priests, altar

Should the Altar in a Catholic Church be reconsecrated after a jr high boy, under the direction of his teacher and sanctioned by the priest, lay on top of the Altar while practicing The Stations of The Cross?

I was horrified when the priest told be it was a beautiful thing to see for The Stations.

Comment: I'm more puzzled how Stations of the Cross is aided by laying on the altar.

Comment: As improper as this is, reconsecration is for more severe situations IIRC

Comment: @eques Like the [reconsecration of the altar, etc. of the Annunciation of the Blessed Virgin Mary Church in Brooklyn, New York](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/255917/brooklyn-church-music-video-altar-desecrated-pastor-disciplined) with a Mass of reparation on Nov 4, 2023?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple the only use of "reconsecration" in that article is indicating that people called for it; however, the article describes a Mass of reparation. Reconsecration would be for when the altar were damaged to a degree it was no longer suitable for use as an altar.

Comment: @eques I see.  So even the situation at the Brooklyn church doesn't canonically require "re-consecration" of the altar?  Should I ask a question on the Catholic Church logic behind the criteria to determine *when* re-consecration is needed?  I wonder whether the OP doesn't mind me revising this question to be more general, relegating the main scenario to be merely an illustration.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple a question about when reconsecration of an altar is needed may be useful. Using a consecrated/blessed space/item for an improper purpose may require reparation; a consecrated thing is only re-consecrated when its integrity is impacted.

Comment: @eques Oh, so re-consecration is a distinct category than reparation?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple right. Only things which are consecrated can strictly be desecrated and thus need to be reconsecrated. Reparation is a lesser/generic restoration when something contrary to the purpose has occurred.